# Keep literal strings between elements xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to parse a simple XML file.  It looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="app_name">Colatris Sample</string>
    <string name="cdata"><![CDATA[<p>Text<p>]]></string>
    <string name="content_description_sample">Something</string>
    <string name="countdown"><xliff:g example="5 days" id="time">%1$s</xliff:g> until holiday</string>
</resources>
```

This is my parsing method:

```
List<CsString> extract(Document document) throws CsException {
    List<CsString> csStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    Element resources  = document.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList strings = resources.getElementsByTagName("string");
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.getLength(); i++) {
        Node string = strings.item(i);
        csStrings.add(new CsString(string.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue(), string.getTextContent()));
    }

    return csStrings;
}
```

I am building the passed Document with this method.

```
Document getDocument()  throws CsException {
    try {
        Application application = core.getApplication();
        AssetManager assetManager = application.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("colatris/values.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        return builder.parse(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
        throw new CsException("Unable to get parser");
    }
}
```

Everything is working great.  Except for the cdata and countdown elements.  I want to just get the literal between the string elements.  However, the parser is only returning the text inside of CDATA and stripping out the xliff tags.

```
String countdown = %1$s until holiday
String cdata = <p>Text<p>
```

I want the parsed strings to look like this so I can persist them literally.  I need to be able to reconstruct XML down the road with the meta data in the correct places.

```
String countdown = <ns1:g example="5 days" id="time">%1$s</ns1:g> until holiday
String cdata = <![CDATA[<p>Text<p>]]>
```

Are there are any configuration tricks for Document in order to keep the nodes between two elements as literal strings?  For most users strpping CDATA makes sense but I need to get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is of course that you are just extracting the text from the `string` element. What you should do is to get the sub-node (or maybe sub-nodes, don't know the exact layout of your files) and output them again using a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`. The code would look something like:

```
    NodeList list = document.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("string");
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = list.item(i);
        Node child = node.getFirstChild();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(child), new StreamResult(writer));
        System.out.println(writer.toString());  // Do your list thing in stead
    }
```